# Function to return list of files to process, what to do when none found

Tags: python-3.x, return-value

I have a Python method that returns a list of files for processing. I create an empty list, and then append files.

If the method does not find any files to process, is there any benefit to checking if the list is empty and **return None** rather than the empty list itself?

With an empty list, the caller is not required to do any checks as the for loop will just not run.

Comment: Why would you want to return `None` rather than an empty list? That makes it harder for callers to use the function, since they have to handle a failed case differently than a successful case. What benefit do you see in doing this?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy That's what I wonder. Could there be any use case for this?